# C# Get character type(s) of a string by Unicode character range data

Tags: c#, unicode

I am not trying to get specific language from a string (one word or two words). That is, not "English" or "German". For example, "Hand" can be both English and German. That seems to be a very complicated work and must rely on some cloud services which cost money and add network delay.

I just want to decide the character type, such as Latin, Chinese, Hiragana, etc, something like those shown here (http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php). I could create my own class and type all those values myself, but it seems a lot of tedious work. I feel as if there should already be something that does that, and I do not want to reinvent the wheel. Is there any library for this?

Comment: Asking for recommendations for external resources, such as libraries, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. However, I can tell you that it's not that difficult to categorize Unicode character code points according to the Unicode specification data. The official site, unicode.org, has downloadable tables with the data, which can easily be parsed and turned into data structures you can use to look up the various attributes, including the script. There probably is a library out there somewhere, but it's not hard to do it yourself either.

Comment: All that said, knowing the script is a long way away from knowing the _language_ of the text. Your example of "hand" is a prime example. English and German both use the Latin script, and so knowing the script isn't going to help you distinguish between the two. Some of the scripts are more specialized, but there is still a lot of overlap between various languages around the world.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Duniho. I am sorry for asking for a library. I thought there might be such feature in the BCL or in some of the things Microsoft provides. If there is no such thing, I will do the parsing of the data from unicode.org. Please close this question.